# Total newbie. Creating map from aerial photo of golf course in QGIS 

Tags: qgis, distance, area

I have a aerial photo in tif with a tfw file of the golf course that I work at.  I would like to create vector data of different features on the course such as greens fairways tees, etc. to calculate areas and distances to start with.  So far I have been able to load the tif into QGIS but after that I am completely lost.  It seems that every tutorial is using data sets that are complete.  I imagine I am creating new data using the raster data? I'm lost.  Thanks for any help

Comment: @Andy put your comment in a answer so we can up vote it for you.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this [QGIS manual](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/manual/qgis-1.0.0_a-gentle-gis-introduction_en.pdf) will get you started, particularly chapter 4 "Data Capture". [Here](http://www.qgis.org/en/documentation/manuals.html) is the page with all of manuals.

Answer (score 3):

As you were with your Image (check the rasters projection) to match it when your creating vector files (shapefiles can be point, line or polygons).

Digitise using the vector tools.

You can attribute fairways differently to the greens and keep it in the same polygon file.

[image]

Here is a guide:
http://www.mapeoamano.org/node/69